# App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

try to push git branch in heroku and shows this error

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add more details to the question. It's hard to understand what is not right with your app as the question is currently written. Ruby and rails versions and `Gemfile` will probably shed some light.

Comment: Do you have a `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` in the root of your repository?

Comment: i'm sorry if the question is hard to understand bcs i dont really know how to describe the proble, so basically i'm trying to deploy my project to heroku and when i try to push to heroku it showed me that the App not compatible with buildpack like my problem above and also it showed ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'heroku-url'.

Comment: yes i do have Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in the root of the repository

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Please [edit] your question and show us a file listing of your top-level directory.

Comment: okay thank you this solved